# Javascript - Applying class to an HTML tag given an attribute/value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to apply styles to HTML tags dynamically by reading in the value of certain HTML attributes and applying a class name based on their values. For instance, if I have:

```
<p height="30">
```

I want to apply a `class="h30"` to that paragraph so that I can style it in my style sheet. I can't find any information on getting the value of an attribute that is not an `id` or `class`. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would highly recommend using something like jquery where adding classes is trivial:

```
$("#someId").addClass("newClass");
```

so in your case:

```
$("p[height='30']").addClass("h30");
```

so this selects all paragraph tags where the height attribute is 30 and adds the class h30 to it.

Answer (score 3):

See: [getAttribute()](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9). Parameter is the name of the attribute (case insensitive). Return value is the value of the attribute (a string).

Be sure to see the [Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536429(VS.85).aspx) in MSDN before dealing with IE...

Answer (score 2):

It's better to separate layout and presentation.

Despite using CSS, you're tying these two together. [Use better class names](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames) (why does it have to have 30px height? Is it menubar? footer? banner?)

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are just properties (usually). So just try:

```
for (e in ...) {
    if (e.height == 30) {
        e.className = "h30";
    }
}
```

Or use something like jquery to simplify this kind of stuff.